# Outlook Add-In office 365 deployment > Add-In not visible

Tags: office365, outlook-addin

I am trying to build my first Outlook Add-In (not VSTO) and followed the tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/quick-start?tabs=visual-studio). After setting up my Office 365 developer license/environment, I finally manage to compile/deploy the Add-In:

```
3>The manifest file "C:\Users\AAX\source\repos\MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\OfficeAppManifests\MyProject.xml" is being deployed to the Exchange server.
3>Successfully registered the mail app on the Exchange Server using service at https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx
```

The compile/deploy action ask me to sign to OWA which I can do but I do not see my Add-In.
I try to a track of my Add-in

1. Search under the OWA > Settings > Manage Add-in --> Nothing
2. Search under Exchange Admin > Settings > Add-In --> Nothing
3. I tried to deploy it manually using OWA: All Ok

The workaround 3 does not help as I want to be able to develop build/deploy in a convenient manner. Any hint on why the Visual Studio deploy does not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the solution was to create a fresh account in the O365 developper subscription and to use that account in Visual Studio to deploy the manifest. After doing so the Add-In appears in Outlook and the OWA portal.

Answer (score 0):

Users can't see add-in? Try one of these:

Use the compatibility checker

- Outputs a status report for each user in your organization, whether they have a valid Office License, if they are set up correctly on Exchange, and if they are ready for centralized deployment. For more information, see [deployment compatibility checker](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55270).

Check Office version requirements

- The user might be on an older, incompatible version of Office. For add-ins to be deployed the user must have Office ProPlus 2016. You can check this out for any member of your organization. To find out how, see [Office 365 reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/activity-reports/microsoft-office-activations?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252foffice-365-reports-in-the-admin-center-microsoft-office-activations-87c24ae2-82e0-4d1e-be01-c3bcc3f18c60&view=o365-worldwide).
- Alternatively, you can check this manually by going to the application, such as Word, then choose File > Account. Under Product Information, you should see **Office 365 ProPlus**.

Check Exchange requirements

- Microsoft Exchange stores the add-in manifests within your organization's tenant. The admin deploying add-ins and the users receiving those add-ins must be on a version of Exchange Server that supports OAuth authentication. By default, Exchange Multi-Tenant and Dedicated VNext deployments support OAuth. Exchange Dedicated Legacy and hybrid on-premises deployments can be configured to support OAuth; however, it isn't the default configuration.
- Check with your organization's Exchange admin to find out which configuration is in use. OAuth connectivity per user can be verified by using the [Test-OAuthConnectivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/organization/Test-OAuthConnectivity?view=exchange-ps) PowerShell cmdlet.

See regulations surrounding minors using add-ins

- Please see further information regarding [minors using add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/manage/manage-deployment-of-add-ins?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fManage-deployment-of-Office-365-add-ins-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-737e8c86-be63-44d7-bf02-492fa7cd9c3f&view=o365-worldwide) if applicable.

For more information, please see the following link:

[Troubleshoot: User not seeing add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/troubleshoot-issues-for-admins/user-not-seeing-add-ins?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252ftroubleshoot-user-not-seeing-add-ins-060e809d-8cb6-427b-9e2f-dab67138acae&view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Hi @Lina, thanks for your feedback even if not really applicable. I run this project in a lab environment and is the Exchange Admin and try using OWA.